# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')

Tags: reactjs

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
fireEvent, logRoles, screen,
} from '@testing-library/react';

import { renderWrapper } from '../../__utils__';


describe('TestingTab', () => {
it('rendering Tab', () => {
const closeSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'close').mockImplementation(() 
=> {});
const providerProps = {
  setCurrentStep: jest.fn(),
  eligibleData: [{

    Name: 'ABC',
    Role: 'XYZ',
    balance: 3694.9,
    Age: 18,
    paymentDue: 1000,
    isChecked: false,
    isEligible: false,
  }],
  setAccount: jest.fn(),

  continueNext: 'no',
  setNextTerms: jest.fn(),
  currentStep: 1,
  wizard: {
    next: jest.fn(() => true),
    previous: jest.fn(),
  },
};
const renderTab = renderWrapper(
  <Project {...providerProps}>
    <Sample />
  </Project>
);
logRoles(renderTab.container);
const checkBoxElement = screen.getByRole('checkbox');
expect(checkBoxElement).toBeDisabled();
const closeButton = screen.getByRole('button');
expect(closeButton).toBeInTheDocument();
fireEvent.click(closeButton);
expect(closeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

closeSpy.mockRestore();
});
});
```

Basically I have a screen on the UI build with react, It has some buttons, etc. i am trying to test this screen using jest test. I am simply trying to check with render test is executing properly. but getting error.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')

Please help.

Comment: There is no `init` in your code, have you included everything?

Comment: Including the full stack trace of the TypeError would help determine the root source of the problem

Comment: at WithWizard (/Users/pparulek/Downloads/Project/node_modules/wizard/node_modules/react-albus/lib/withWizard.js:40:28)
    at renderWithHooks (/Users/pparulek/Downloads/Project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (/Users/pparulek/Downloads/Project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811:13)
    at beginWork (/Users/pparulek/Downloads/Project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19049:16)